# java: Lombok visitor handler class lombok.javac.handlers.HandleVal failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: TypeSymbol.isLocal()

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

I am trying to build Springboot project with Maven but getting below error while running it on tomcat server .

Please suggest a solution . Thanks .

```
java: Lombok visitor handler class lombok.javac.handlers.HandleVal failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol.isLocal()'
```

Lombok

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.4/libexec
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Users/psingh/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: US-ASCII
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.1", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Tomcat

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.55/libexec
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.55/libexec
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.55/libexec/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Users/psingh/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.11.0-11/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.55/libexec/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@9/9.0.55/libexec/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.55
Server built:   Nov 10 2021 08:26:45 UTC
Server number:  9.0.55.0
OS Name:        Mac OS X
OS Version:     11.1
Architecture:   x86_64
JVM Version:    11.0.11+9
JVM Vendor:     AdoptOpenJDK
```

Answer (score 6):

I have updated Lombok to 1.18.24 .
It solved the issue !!
Now it is running in IntelliJ idea on Tomcat server .

Comment: updating Lombok to 1.18.24 didn't work in my case.